# regular expression for decimal digit validation

Tags: c#, regex

Regular expression for C# data annotations to validate a optional decimal number with below conditions

- max eleven digits starting with any digit between 0-9 (after lead zeros count should be 11)
- max eleven digits with a decimal point starting with any digit between 0-9, count with
  decimal should not exceed 11
- it cannot be just a zero
- only one decimal allowed in the whole number but decimal is not required

**example:**

```
12345678910
10.3
0.02
18.2578
012345678.9 
0.123456789 
012345678912 (since lead zero doesn't count as a valid number count 
              of max 11 is after zeor)
0.123456789 (since this number has decimal lead zero counts to the 
             total 11 digit count)
0.001
```

So far I have come-up with something like this `^(?=.{1,11}$)([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])?$` but this is not working for all cases

this is how I set data annotation

```
 [RegularExpression(@"(?<![.\d])0*(?:[1-9][0-9]{10}|(?![0-9.]{14})(?:0\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+))(?![0-9.])\z", ErrorMessage = "Invalid {0}")]
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
```

Comment: what about `012345678.9`? Is it valid match?

Comment: is `.1234567890` a valid match?

Comment: @Braj yes 012345678.9 and .1234567890 are valid matches as they are still not exceeding count 11 with decimal point

Comment: what about this `12.34.56789`?

Comment: @Braj only one decimal allowed in the whole number but decimal is not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
\A0*(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,10}|(?![0-9.]{12})(?:0\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+))\z
```

details:

```
\A                            # start of the string anchor
0*                            # ignored leading zeros
(?:
    [1-9][0-9]{0,10}            # integer
  |
    (?![0-9.]{12})            # 11 characters max for decimal numbers
    (?:
        0\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*  # decimal numbers < 1
      |
        [1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+   # decimal numbers >= 1
    )
)
\z                            # end of the string anchor
```

[**online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/eY7pJ1/3)

code example:

```
string text = "1.1231231";
string pat = @"
    \A                            # start of the string anchor
    0*                            # ignored leading zeros
    (?:
        [1-9][0-9]{0,10}          # integer numbers
      |
        (?![0-9.]{12})            # 11 characters max for decimal numbers
        (?:
            0\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*  # decimal numbers < 1
          |
            [1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+   # decimal numbers >= 1
        )
    )
    \z                            # end of the string anchor
";

Regex r = new Regex(pat, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

Match m = r.Match(text);

if (m.Success) {
    /* OK */
} else {
   /* FAIL */
}
```

With data-annotations:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,10}|(?![0-9.]{12})(?:0\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+))$", 
  ErrorMessage="Invalid number!")]
```

Comment: your pattern says 10.3 is invalid it is a valid decimal

Comment: @HaBo: `10.3` works well, you made a mistake. I will add an online demo. *(with lookaround in place of anchors to have several results)*

Comment: So all blue and green colored are passed?

Comment: @HaBo: yes, all highlighted substrings.

Comment: I am using it in C# data-annotations I set it as (?<![.\d])
0*(?:[1-9][0-9]{10}|(?![0-9.]{14})(?:0\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+))(?![0-9.]) then it give Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<![.\d])0*(?:[1-9][0-9]{10}|(?![0-9.]{14})(?:0\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+))(?![0-9.])\z/: Invalid group

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57702/discussion-between-habo-and-casimir-et-hippolyte).

Comment: @HaBo: I added an implementation example and an the correct syntax for data-annotations.

Comment: it is always expecting decimal. decimal is not required

Comment: your pattern is working for all cases except decimal is optional such as 2 or 10, 45 should be valid numbers. can you explain how to add it?

Comment: @HaBo: It is because in you previous requirements you didn't write that integers with less than 11 significant digits are allowed. I have udapted my answer.

Comment: sorry. We are close but your latest answer considers 10.2345678910 as valid length of the full decimal number including decimal point should not exceed 11 here it is 13

Comment: (?<![.\d])0*(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,10}|(?![0-9.]{12})(?:0\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*|[1-9][0-9]*\.[0-9]+))(?![0-9.])

Answer (score 0):

IMHO regular expression for verifying a possible floating point number is very inefficient, becuase you are invoking a much larger parser than needed for the job.

It may be better to use `Convert` class and use methods `ToDecimal` or `ToDouble` throw a `FormatException` exception

Comment: We have no idea what `strtod`, `strtold` and `strtof` here. And note we're talking about c#.

Comment: Woops! I am flaky today

Comment: But how about the length check and if decimal exist? do all that in C#?

Answer (score 0):

This should match everything, but the max length

```
0*[1-9]+[0-9]*(?:[.][\d]+)?|0+[.][\d]+
```